# Why is my service running before anything else?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, angular-services, ui-grid

I'm new to services, factories, etc; so there's still a lot I don't understand.

I have a ui-grid. When a row is selected, I want to use that data as a param in a service to get REST data to populate another grid.

This is what I think it should be doing:

> `gridOne` is registered => Row Selected => Send `selectedRow.id` to Service => Service GETs data => data populates grid 2

This is what its actually doing:

> Service GETs data => Error because `selectedRow.id` is not defined.

```
01| $scope.gridOne.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
02|     $scope.gridOneApi = gridApi
03|     $scope.gridOneApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged(null, function(row){
04|         $scope.gridOneSelectedRow = $scope.gridOneApi.selection.getSelectedRows()[0]
05|
06|         // v---Breakpoint on this line triggered before any grid is built---v
07|         myService.getAllObjects($scope.gridOneSelectedRow.id).then(response => {
08|             $scope.grid2.data = response
09|         }
10|     })
11| }
```

My service looks like this:

```
app.service('myService', function ($http) {

    return {
        get: getObjects
    }

    function getOjects(id) {
        let url = `http://${domain}/object/${id}`
        return $http.get(url).then(response => {
            return response
        }).catch(error => {
            return error
        })
    }
}
```

### Why is the service function running before everything else?

Comment: and, if you are returning something, why it is `.service`, they are supposed to newed up by angular and you have to provide a constructor. in the case you are returning something, better to use `factory` (or `provider`, depending on your requirement )

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee OK, thanks. So a factory / provider will run when it is called?

Comment: yes, you should, in `provider` it will return whatever you returned from your `$get` function. but it seems your problem is something else. you are trying to get some remote data with `http` call, so it is an async operation, and your code will not wait for it, so yourfunction executes immediately. it is returning a promise. try to use that promise with `then` and pass a callback at the injecting end of this service.

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee Can you post an answer describing what you mean please?

Comment: Sure! wait a moment :)

Comment: @georgeawg, I think he is selecting another grid `gridOne` and on selection of a row of `gridOne` he want to load corresponding data to another grid `grid2`

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee you are correct. `grid2` needs to know the id of the selected row in gridOne in order to determine its data. That's why the data is populated inside `on.rowSelectionChanged`. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

if you are writing a service, you should not return a object/function/something, your implementation function is used as a constructor to newed up and create instance of your service.

so if you want to use a service, a sample for your `myService` will be

```
app.service('myService', function ($http) {
    function getOjects(id) {
        //you should properly replace your domain, may be with the same domain by default if you start from object/...
        let url = `http://${domain}/object/+ id`
        return $http.get(url).then(response => {
            return response.data
        }).catch(error => {
            return error
        })
    }
    this.getAllObjects = getOjects;
})
```

in case of factory

```
app.factory('myService', function ($http) {
    function getOjects(id) {
        //you should properly replace your domain, may be with the same domain by default if you start from object/...
        let url = `http://${domain}/object/+ id`
        return $http.get(url).then(response => {
            return response.data
        }).catch(error => {
            return error
        })
    }
    return {getAllObjects: getOjects};
})
```

and in the injecting end you don't need to change the code the way you are using it to load data, just wrote the code in sync of use
and also, I wnder, why you are trying to select before the data is loaded, and inside the handler of row selection you want to call the data when now row is present at all, if the data is not loaded, right? I hope you are loading data for another grid `grid2` on selection of a row of `grid1`, and then want to load corresponding data related to that row to `grid2`.

Feel free to comment, whatever doubt you still have.

Good Luck :)

Comment: Thanks for this help. But, to clarify, `grid2` is assigned data inside the `gridOneApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged` event, so it should only be triggered once a row from `gridOne` is selected.

Comment: Yeah, got that. That was my default assumption :)